# CGroup configuration in CentOS 7

Tags: configuration, memory, centos7, systemd, cgroup

I am using CentOS 7 and I have several users registered in system (UIDs: 1000, 1001, 1002, etc)

I want to restrict memory consumption for each user using cgroup and systemd.

The following commands work pretty well but the user with UID=1000 must be logged in.

```
systemctl set-property user-1000.slice MemoryLimit=3000M
systemctl daemon-reload
```

If the user is not login I receive the following error message

```
Failed to set unit properties on user-1000.slice: Unit user-1000.slice is not loaded.
```

Imagine I have 20 users and I want to set up memory restrictions for them. Should I log in manually or write some workaround script to do it in order to run `systemctl set-property` command for each user? Or some elegant and straightforward solution exists?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage

> The limits imposed by `ulimit` and `limits.conf` is per process. I definitely wasn't clear on that point.
>
> If you want to limit the total amount of memory a users uses (which is what you asked). You want to use cgroups.
>
> In `/etc/cgconfig.conf`:
>
> ```
> group memlimit {
>     memory {
>         memory.limit_in_bytes = 4294967296;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This creates a `cgroup` that has a max memory limit of 4GiB.
>
> In `/etc/cgrules.conf`:
>
> ```
> luser   memory   memlimit/
> ```
>
> This will cause all processes run by `luser` to be run inside the `memlimit` cgroups created in `cgconfig.conf`.